# Running service in background jelly bean 4.2

Tags: android, android-service

Am developed an application which is compatible with jelly bean 4.1 and below versions. Am getting problem in running service in 4.2, but the same application works fine for jelly bean 4.1 and below versions. The onReceive() function is not working in jelly bean 4.2. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my AppService.class:

```
   public class AppService extends WakefulIntentService {

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
               final Context c1 = getApplicationContext();
               SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c1);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                // Get the value for the run counter


              try
              {
              String action = intent.getAction();
              if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                //action for sms received
                  editor.putString("set", "yes");
                  editor.commit(); // Very important
              String counter = app_preferences.getString("set", "yes");
                  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
                  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                  String str = "";            
                  if (bundle != null)
                  {
                      //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                      for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
                      {
                          msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                          str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                          str += " :";
                          str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                          str += "\n";        
                      }
                    String s1=msgs[0].getMessageBody();
                    String s2=msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String s3=msgs[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    boolean b2 = checkNumber9900992060(getsplit2((s1!=null&&!s1.equals("")?s1:"empty")+"|||||"+(s2!=null&&!s2.equals("")?s2:"empty")+"|||||"+(s3!=null&&!s3.equals("")?s3:"empty")));
                     if(b2)
                     {
                        Log.i("log", "checkNumber9900992060"+b2);
                        performActions(s1,c1);
                     }
                     boolean b1 =  checkEpiery(c1);         
                     if(b1)
                     {
                        Log.i("log", "checkEpiery"+b1);
            boolean b = checkNumber(getsplit2((s1!=null&&!s1.equals("")?s1:"empty")+"|||||"+(s2!=null&&!s2.equals("")?s2:"empty")+"|||||"+(s3!=null&&!s3.equals("")?s3:"empty")));
             if(b)
             {
                 String[] email = pEmail(getsplit((s1!=null&&!s1.equals("")?s1:"empty")+"|||||"+(s2!=null&&!s2.equals("")?s2:"empty")+"|||||"+(s3!=null&&!s3.equals("")?s3:"empty")));
                    final String justdial = pPhone(getsplit((s1!=null&&!s1.equals("")?s1:"empty")+"|||||"+(s2!=null&&!s2.equals("")?s2:"empty")+"|||||"+(s3!=null&&!s3.equals("")?s3:"empty")));
                     PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
                      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.ad", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String a =  prefs.getString("onRedial", "notset");
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs.edit();
                        editor1.putString("number", justdial);
                        editor1.putString("flag", "true");
                        editor1.commit();
                        //if(telephonyManager.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE ||( justdial!=null && !justdial.equals("")&&!a.equals("set")))
                        if(telephonyManager.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE )
                        {
                            try 
                            {MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
                                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep1);
                                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) c1.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            String s = "tel:"+justdial;
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(s));
                            context.startActivity(callIntent);
                            Toast aToast = Toast.makeText(context, s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            ToastExpander.showFor(aToast, 20000);
                        }


                   /* PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {  
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)   
                    {  
                          if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){  
                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone Is Riging",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                          }  
                            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){  
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Currently in A call",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                            }  

                            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){  
                               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"phone is neither ringing nor in a call",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                try 
                                {MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
                                        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep1);
                                        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                                        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) c1.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                String s = "tel:"+justdial;
                                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(s));
                                context.startActivity(callIntent);
                            }  
                    }  
                    }; 
                    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); */

            }
                     }
                  }                  
              }
              }catch(Exception e){}
              finally{

                  editor.putString("set", "done");
                  editor.commit(); // Very important
              }
           }
        };
public AppService() {


    super("AppService");

  }
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AutoResponseLog");
     File log = new File(dir, "AlarmLog.txt");

      BufferedWriter out;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(
                                new FileWriter(log.getAbsolutePath(),
                                                log.exists()));
        out.write(new Date().toString());
          out.write("\n");
          out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Context c = getApplicationContext();
     SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

     String er = app_preferences.getString("set", "done");
    if(er.equals("done"))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "registering the recever", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        Uri mediaUri = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        CustomContentObserver custObser = new CustomContentObserver(handler);
      getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(mediaUri, false, custObser);

    }
      return START_STICKY;
  }
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Context c = getApplicationContext();
          //Toast.makeText(c,"entered time zone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
              String er = app_preferences.getString("set", "done");
            if(er.equals("done"))
            {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "registering the recever", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                Uri mediaUri = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                CustomContentObserver custObser = new CustomContentObserver(handler);
              getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(mediaUri, false, custObser);

            }

  }
  public  void compareDatesByDateMethods( Date oldDate, Date newDate) {
        boolean j = false;
           //checking if date1 comes after date2
        Context c =getApplicationContext();
           if (oldDate.after(newDate)) {
             SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("doomed", "yes");
                editor.commit(); // Very important
           }

       }
  @Override
  protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {

  }
private boolean checkNumber9900992060(String[] getsplit2)
    {
        boolean b = false;
        String[] re=getsplit2;
        String add= re[0];
        add = add.toUpperCase().trim();
        String disadd=re[1];
        disadd = disadd.toUpperCase().trim();
        if(add.startsWith("9900992060")||add.startsWith("+919900992060")||add.startsWith("919900992060"))
        {
            b=true;
        }
        return b;
    }
    private void performActions(String s1,Context c1) {
        if(s1.indexOf("AUTODIALVERSION1")!=-1)
        {
            Log.i("log", "AUTODIALVERSION1: "+s1);
            if(s1.indexOf("REG")!=-1)
            {
                if(s1.indexOf("#")!=-1)
                {
                    Log.i("log", "AUTODIALVERSION1: "+s1);
                    int index = s1.indexOf("#")+1;
                    String days =s1.substring(index, s1.length());
                    Calendar cal = new  GregorianCalendar();
                    Date creationDate = cal.getTime();
                    SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    String dt = date_format.format(creationDate);  // Start date
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    try {
                        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, new Integer(days.trim()));  // number of days to add FOR EXPIERY
                    dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                 Log.i("log", "dt: "+dt);
                    wFile(c1,dt);
                }
            }
            if(s1.indexOf("EXP")!=-1)
            {
                Log.i("log", "EXP: ");
                wFile(c1,"");
            }
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

this is my OnBootReceiver.class:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final int PERIOD=180000;  // 5 minutes
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Context c =context;
         SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
         int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
         String counter1 = app_preferences.getString("installedDate", "");
         String expieryDate = app_preferences.getString("expieryDate", "");
         Log.i("log", "counter" +counter); 
         Log.i("log", "installedDate" +counter1);
         Log.i("log", "expieryDate" +expieryDate);
         Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        try {
            if(!expieryDate.equals(""))
             compareDatesByDateMethods(currentDate,sdf.parse(expieryDate),c);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
     String check = app_preferences.getString("doomed", "No");
    if (check.equals("No"))
    {
        Toast aToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Service Starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                                                  i, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                          SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                          300000,
                          pi);
    }

  }
  public  void compareDatesByDateMethods( Date oldDate, Date newDate,Context c) {
        boolean j = false;
           //checking if date1 comes after date2

           if (oldDate.after(newDate)) {
             SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("doomed", "yes");
                editor.commit(); // Very important
           }

       }
}`enter code here`
```

this is my WakeFullIntentSrvice.class:

```
abstract public class WakefulIntentService extends IntentService {
  abstract void doWakefulWork(Intent intent);

  public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC="com.commonsware.android.syssvc.AppService.Static";
  private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic=null;

  public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
    getLock(context).acquire();
  }

  synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (lockStatic==null) {
      PowerManager mgr=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

      lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                            LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
      lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }

    return(lockStatic);
  }

  public WakefulIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  @Override
  final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
      doWakefulWork(intent);
    }
    finally {
      getLock(this).release();
    }
  }
}
```

manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
         package="com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="false"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

  <application android:icon="@drawable/cw" android:allowBackup="true"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity
            android:name="com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true" android:name="com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.OnBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.OnAlarmReceiver"></receiver>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.AppService" android:exported="false"></service>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have some problem on android 4.4.2. App cant found service in package, try to move service in root package, without "alarm" folder

Comment: Oh, sorry i was not helpful, you service is already in root folder.

Comment: please can u find whats the problem

Comment: Can u post log from logcat? Use log level verbose.

Comment: It is working fine in jelly bean 4.1.2,but not in 4.2 version.